# How to skip found values

Tags: javascript, angular

How to skip found values in else condition, now in my code it outputs duplicates.

```js
 this.comparedGenesList = this.genesList.map((item) => {
      const foundedItem = this.data.probes.find(({name}) => name.toUpperCase() === item.toUpperCase());
        if (foundedItem !== undefined) {
         return {name: foundedItem.name.trim(), matched: true, id: foundedItem.id};
        } else {
          return {name: item.trim(), matched: false, id: undefined};
        }
    });
```

Comment: You looking for `.filter()`?

Comment: i tried but how can filter in my situation? (in map)

Comment: `.map()` is a transform method; if you give it an array of length N, it will output an array of length N. Skipping duplicates shouldn't enter in its logic. _After_ the `.map()`, what you should do is chain a `.filter()` to [remove the duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tack an `array.filter` on the end to remove all duplicates.

```
.filter((item, index, array) =>  
  index === array.findIndex((t) => (
    t.name === item.name && t.id === item.id
  ))
)
```

which basically says

> For each item in the array, perform a test to see if we need to filter
> it out. The test is: find the first matching object with the same name
> and id as the one we're testing. If the index of that found object is
> the same as the index of the one we're testing, let it through. If
> it's a different index (as in, we found a duplicate later on) discard
> it.

Here is a testable snippet:

```js
this.genesList = ['fred','john','dave','john','dave']
this.data = {probes:[{name:'john', id:2}]}

this.comparedGenesList = this.genesList.map((item) => {
  const foundedItem = this.data.probes.find(({name}) => name.toUpperCase() === item.toUpperCase());
  if (foundedItem !== undefined) {
    return {
      name: foundedItem.name.trim(),
      matched: true,
      id: foundedItem.id
    };
  } else {
    return {
      name: item.trim(),
      matched: false,
      id: undefined
    };
  }
}).filter((item, index, array) =>
  index === array.findIndex((t) => (
    t.name === item.name && t.id === item.id
  ))
)

console.log(this.comparedGenesList )
```

Comment: its works thanks, can u describe what happens in filter? interesting construction !

Comment: I updated it with a description, hopefully it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter() rather than map().

```
this.comparedGenesList = this.genesList.filter((item) => {
  const isItemFounded = this.data.probes.some((name) => name.toUpperCase() === item.toUpperCase());
  return !isItemFounded;
})
.map((item) => {
      return {name: item.name.trim(), matched: true, id: item.id};
});
```